# When is random variable $\xi$ independent of itself?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Exercise: When is random variable $\xi$ independent of itself?

$\xi$ and $\xi$ are independent if and only if $P(\xi < t_1, \xi < t_2) = P(\xi < t_1) P(\xi < t_2).$

If $t_1 > t_2$, then  $P(\xi < t_1, \xi < t_2) = P(\xi < t_2) = P(\xi < t_1) P(\xi < t_2) \Longrightarrow 1 = P(\xi < t_1).$

If $t_1 = t_2$, then also $1 = P(\xi < t_1).$

Case $t_2 > t_1$ is symmetric to the first one.

What confuses me is that $t_1$ is arbitrary, so for any arbitrarily large positive $N$ $$1=P(\xi < -N).$$

By definition of a random variable, values of $\xi$ belong to real numbers, so there's no way we can have $P(\xi = -\infty) = 1,$ and $P(\xi = r) = 0, \ \ r \in \mathbb{R}.$

What am I doing wrong?

The textbook answer is "$\xi$ has degenerate distribution".

Comment: A $\sigma$-field is independent of itself if and only if it is trivial. It follows that for all Borel sets $B$, $P(\xi \in B) \in \{0,1\}$. Since the distribution function is non-decreasing, and $F(\infty)=1-F(-\infty)=1$, one concludes $\xi$ is a dirac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$P(\xi<t)=P(\xi<t,\xi<t)=P(\xi<t)^2,$$
we find $P(\xi<t)\in\{0,1\}$.
For $t_1<t_2$, we have
$$P(\xi<t_1)=P(\xi<t_1,\xi<t_2)=P(\xi<t_1)P(\xi<t_2),$$
so
$$P(\xi<t_1)(P(\xi<t_1)-P(\xi<t_2))=0, $$
which is equivalent to
$$ P(\xi<t_1)=0\quad\lor\quad P(\xi<t_1)=P(\xi<t_2).$$
Going only by these poroperties, $P(\xi<t)$ as a function of $t$ may be of the form
$$\tag1P(\xi<t)=\begin{cases}0&t<t_0\\1&t\ge t_0\end{cases}$$
for some $t_0\in\mathbb R$,
or
$$\tag2P(\xi<t)=\begin{cases}0&t\le t_0\\1&t> t_0\end{cases}$$
for some $t_0\in\mathbb R$,
or
$$\tag3P(\xi<t)=0$$
or
$$\tag4P(\xi<t)=1$$
Now check, which of these possibilities produce valid distributions.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Shouldn't the third formula (non-numbered) be $P(\xi<t_1)(1-P(\xi<t_2))=0$ instead of $P(\xi<t_1)(P(\xi<t_1)-P(\xi<t_2))=0$ ?